# Событие другого объекта

Tags: c#, события

Есть следующая проблема: есть класс соединения, держащий в себе всю информацию для дальнейшей работы приложения. Некоторые свойства этого класса обновляется с интерфейса и после изменения отрабатывает событие, определенное в этом же классе. Если обработчик события поместить в этот класс - оно отрабатывает на изменение свойства, а если же попытаться подписать метод другого класса, который получает объект соединения в конструкторе и инициализирует его - событие не отрабатывает, подписчиков нет.
Примерный код:

```
sealed class Conn
{
    private int age;
    private string name;
    delegate void UI ();
    public event UI UserEvent;
}

private class work
{
    private Conn _conn;
    public work(Conn conn)
    {
        _conn = conn;
    }
    private void MajorWork
    {
        _conn.UserEvent +=eventWorker;
    }

    private eventWorker(){}
}
```

`conn.UserEvent +=eventWorker`. В результате подписки не происходит, в дебаггере видно, что нет подписчиков. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно подписаться на событие. Я не вижу чтобы вы в коде вызывали `MajorWork`. Это можно сделать, например, в конструкторе класса `work`:

```
private class Work
{
    private Conn _conn;
    public Work(Conn conn)
    {
        _conn = conn;
        MajorWork();
    }
    private void MajorWork
    {
        _conn.UserEvent +=eventWorker;
    }

    private eventWorker(){}
}
```

Comment: Это условный код. Конечно я вызываю метод, где подписываюсь на событие. Однако подписки не происходит. Если я попробую подписаться путем создания нового экземпляра класса Conn - все будет работать. А если передавать объект - подписки не происходит.

Comment: @Sleeeper Посмотрите этот пример http://pastebin.com/Eh2B7SMK

Comment: да, указанная реализация будет работать. Однако нужен другой эффект. Нужно в классе Work подписаться на событие из класса Conn, при этом не создавая нового экземпляра Conn в Work, а получив объект Conn в конструкторе.

Comment: @Sleeeper по ссылке так и есть. Создается Конн, потом он передается в Ворк и в нем идет подписка на событие. Что-то я вас не пойму :( Пришлите ваш полный пример... Будем смотреть...

Comment: conn.Raise() должен вызываться в Work, куда Conn передается. Вот разница.

Comment: @Sleeeper Так тоже можно. Райз на Конн вызывается из Ворк http://pastebin.com/AcJLWnMk Без вашего примера, который не работает, мы долго будем искать ошибку...

Comment: pavelip ,Вы просто дергаете метод другого класса, который дергает свой event. Я же хочу, чтобы обработчик события находился в классе work, а само событие в классе Conn. Должно быть так: _conn.UserEvent +=this.eventWorker; Где this это Work

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Поставлю вам плюс. Косяк был с тем, что было несколько объектов с событием, на которое я подписывался.